# How to use 'loc' for column selection of a dataframe in dask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, distributed, dask

Anyone can tell me how i should select one column with 'loc' in a dataframe using dask?

As a side note, when i am loading the dataframe using dd.read_csv with header equals to "None", the column name is starting from zero to 131094. I am about to select the last column with column name as 131094, and i get the error.

code:

```
> import dask.dataframe as dd
> df = dd.read_csv('filename.csv', header=None)
> y = df.loc['131094']
```

error:

File "/usr/local/dask-2018-08-22/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask-0.5.0-py2.7.egg/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 180, in _loc
    "Can not use loc on DataFrame without known divisions")
ValueError: Can not use loc on DataFrame without known divisions

Based on this guideline http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-indexing.html#positional-indexing, my code should work right but don't know what causes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a named column, then use: `df.loc[:,'col_name']`
But if you have a positional column, like in your example where you want the last column, then use the answer by @user1717828.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on a dummy csv and it worked.  I can't help you for sure without seeing the file giving you problems. That said, you might be picking rows, not columns.

Instead, try this.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('filename.csv', header=None)
y = df[df.columns[-1]]
```

Comment: Well i am getting this error:                                                                                    File "/usr/local/dask-2018-08-22/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask-0.5.0-py2.7.egg/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 452, in __getitem__
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError